# Notification remoteview duplicates when startforeground called more than once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-remoteview

In a service I have a main remoteview

```
notRemoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
```

and to that I add another remoteview which contains an ImageButton

```
RemoteViews btnView1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.btn1);
notRemoteView.addView(R.id.image_button_container, btnView1);
```

after that I call:

```
startForeground(requestCode, notification);
```

It all works fine and does the appropriate action when clicked but then the ImageButton gets duplicated. The btnView1 remoteview seems to get re-added to the main remoteview. With each button click another button is added to the notification. This happens even when I null both of the remotveiws before building the notification.

I used to have the ImageButton as part of the main remoteview originally and it worked perfectly fine. 
Note: I use `startForeground(requestCode, notification);` with the same requestCode, is this the right way to update service/background notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to remove all remoteviews each time I wanted to update notification:

```
notRemoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
notRemoteView.removeAllViews(R.id.image_button_container);
```

Thanks to this answer: [Android app widget: content added twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485427/android-app-widget-content-added-twice)

Comment: You're removing removeViews AFTER you create them?